# How do I increment a NSUInteger variable?

Tags: iphone, nsuinteger

```
NSUInteger wordInt = sentence.length;
```

I want to add 1 like this -> `wordInt = wordInt + 1 ;`

But It doesn't work. I don't know....

Please!!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should work. So should `wordInt++`. `NSUInteger` is a (typedef'd) primitive type.

Please post more code so we can see the context.